# In Classification, can feature engineering by frequent one-hot encoding prove ineffective?

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression, statsmodels, feature-engineering

**Short context**

After I completed feature engineering, my dataset expanded from 15 columns to around 90. Over 90% of my new dataset is one-hot encoded (most values in columns are 0s and 1s across the dataset). After using *statsmodels* and running Logistic Regression summary, my pseudo R-2 is only at 0.07, and continues to decrease as I remove statistically insignificant features.

**Main question**

Is it possible to over feature-engineer using one-hot encoding? I did as much feature engineering as I could to extract as much data as I could, so my low pseudo R-2 value confuses as to why it is so low.

I have been doing Machine Learning for 3 months, and I was taught to extract as much info as I could in feature engineering before testing models. After doing just that, I am genuinely stuck with my current knowledge as to why my pseudo R-2 may be as low as it is.

**Long Context**

I am working on a personal project using public dataset. The ultimate goal is to predict which customers are likely to not show up for their scheduled appointment. I started with 11 explanatory variables and 1 response variable - Outcome. Originally, my explanatory variables were:

- Gender (F/M)
- Scheduled Day ('date time' object)
- Appointment Day ('date time' object)
- Age
- Neighborhood (many different ones)
- Scholarship (0/1 values)
- Hypertension (0/1 values)
- Diabetes (0/1 values)
- Alcoholism (0/1 values)
- Handicap (0/1 values)
- SMS received (0/1 values)

I want this project to be my exemplary project as a new data scientist, so I feature engineered as much as I could. Examples include:

- Extracting the name of the month from dates, and then one-hot-encoding so every month is in its column
- Extracting the day of the week, and then one-hot-encoding so every day of the week is in its own column
- Splitting times by AM and PM, and storing that info in on-hot encoded columns
- Identifying outliers for Age column and storing them in separate columns, and more

Once I completed my feature engineering, I used *statsmodels* to run the Logistic Regression summary of my model using the following code example:

```
smf.logit(formula = """ Outcome ~ 
                                       Age +
                                       Scholarship + ...)
```

After I completed everything, my pseudo R-2 value is only 0.07 at best. I did my research and found that pseudo R-2 value between 0.2 and 0.4 means a model is strong. Therefore, it confuses me as to why my score is so low after extracting all information I possibly could.

Comment: How many observations do you have? Did you try a model with just the original dataset? Dont want to be a bummer but sometime there are no real relations that can be obtained

Comment: @J.Doe I haven't tried running a summary with just original variables. Overall, I have a little over 9,000 observations, 75% of them are in the test set, so the model should have enough observations to be trained on.

Comment: What's the fraction of missed appointments? If that fraction is small, then pseudo-R2 and similar total measures are not very informative, e.g. If only 2% miss appointment, then a constant prediction, appointment is not missed, will have a 98 % success rate, and any fancy model can only improve by at most 2 %.

Comment: @Josef in my training set, I have 1366 people who missed an appointment, and 5492 who showed up; 20% of people missed an appointment. I am a new to data science, and working on a class imbalance project to learn to build models that effectively predict smaller class. Are you suggesting that this should be the end of my analysis, given there is no clear relation between explanatory variables and outcome? I also posted a new question, will be grateful for your input: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61031367/in-classification-does-a-very-low-pseudo-r-2-value-indicate-no-need-for-further

Comment: It's possible that those variables don't have predictive power, but it's surprising. Check confusion table, and cases where prediction is close to 0 or 1 and see if they have any distinguishing features. Run logistic regression in sklearn to see if penalized does better, verify model and data. If all fails, then I would give up, but I wouldn't stop just because of a low pseudo-R2.

Comment: @Josef thank you for this insight. In fact, this is exactly what I am doing now! Thank you for your help, and I will continue to problem-solve this issue.